# Binomial series differential equation

Tags: binomial-theorem

Show that

> $$(1 + x) g'(x) = \ell g(x)$$

where $$g(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } x^k \binom{\ell}{k}$$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } x^k \binom{\ell}{k}=(1+x)^{\ell}$$
$$g'(x)=\ell(1+x)^{\ell-1}$$
$$(1+x)g'(x)=\ell(1+x)(1+x)^{\ell-1}=\ell(1+x)^{\ell}=\ell g(x)$$

Comment: Please don't give answers to questions that show no effort.